# creating types on the fly for collection type

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible to create FormType on the fly and avoid manually creating new form type class.

Currently I have to do this:

MyController.php

```
$builder = $this->createBuilder(new ParentEntity());
$builder
  ->add('parentfield1')
  ->add('parentfield2');
  ->add('children', 'collection', array('type' => new ChildType());
```

ChildType.php

```
class ChildType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('childname1')
                ->add('childname2');
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'ChildEntity',
        );
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'childentity';
    }

}
```

I would like to avoid creating ChildType class manually and do something like this instead:

MyController.php

```
$childBuilder = $this->createBuilder(new ChildEntity());
$childBuilder
   ->add('childfield1')
   ->add('childfield2');

// how to create FormType from builder???
$childType = $childBuilder->??????;

$builder = $this->createBuilder(new ParentEntity());
$builder
  ->add('parentfield1')
  ->add('parentfield2');
  ->add('children', 'collection', array('type' => $childType);
```

I tried to get the type with:

```
$childBuilder->->getFormConfig()->getType();
```

but that did not work. I get error:

The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Namespace\Bundle\Entity\ChildEntity, but is an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection to an instance of Namespace\Bundle\Entity\ChildEntity.

Currently the best I came up with is to create custom FormType that accepts array of fields as constructor but is there a better way?

Comment: First of all, you should create [form classes](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes).

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. My first example is form class: `class ChildType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType`